# Readiness probe failure for Postgres because of "root"

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes-statefulset, readinessprobe

I am trying to execute the very standard `SELECT 1` command as a `readiness` probe command.
I've been through numerous posts on Postgres, root user and Kubernetes but I still can't get it right although this might be trivial.

I defined ENV variables `POSTGRES_USER=postgres` and `POSTGRES_DB=mydb` in the config manifest of my Postgres StatefulSet manifest.

I understood I had to use `bash` to execute a command since ENV variables are [not interpolated](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40846).

All following commands fail with **FATAL, role "root**

```sh
bash -c pg_isready -U $POSTGRES_USER -p 5432 -> FATAL

bash -c psql -w -U $POSTGRES_USER -d $POSTGRES_DB -c 'SELECT 1;' -> FATAL

# bash doesn't read ENV ?
bash -c psql -w -U $POSTGRES_USER -d mydb -c 'SELECT 1;' -> FATAL

# maybe current user from host? "me" from "whoami"
bash -c psql -w -U me -d postgres -c 'SELECT 1;' -> FATAL
```

Then I execute the commands to check if `bash` gets the ENV variables -> NO

```sh
kubectl exec -it pg-dep-0 -- bash -c psql -U $POSTGRES_USER -d $POSTGRES_DB -c 'SELECT 1;' -> FATAL

kubectl exec -it pg-dep-0 -- bash -c psql -U $POSTGRES_USER -d $POSTGRES_DB -c 'SELECT 1;' -> FATAL

kubectl exec -it pg-dep-0 -- psql -U $POSTGRES_USER -d $POSTGRES_DB -c 'SELECT 1;' -> FATAL
```

but:

```sh
kubectl exec -it pg-dep-0 -- psql -U postgres -c 'SELECT 1;' <-- correct

kubectl exec -it pg-dep-0 -- sh
   / # echo $POSTGRES_USER
   postgres   <-- correct
```

succeeds, without bash but no ENV variable.

Finally, setting directly the values and not using `bash` with `psql -U postgres -c 'SELECT 1;` (without `bash`)  as the command for the `readiness` probe also fails: Postgres is up, but the test returns "Readiness probe failed".

I used directly:

```yaml
spec.tempalte.spec.containers:
[...]
  envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: config
  readinessProbe:
     exec:
       command:
         - bash
         - "-c"
         - |
           psql -U "postgres" -d "mydb" -c 'SELECT 1;'
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config
data:
  POSTGRES_HOST: "pg-svc" 
  POSTGRES_DB: "mysb"
  POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
```

A bit lost, any advice?

Comment: Instead of making up your own `env` variables why not use the ones `libpq` understands [Env](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) and then you could use the `libpq` based clients(psql, pg_isready) without going through bash as you did with: `psql -U postgres -c 'SELECT 1;'` Which works by the way because not specifying `-d`  defaults to using the user name as the database name.

Comment: Because I followed the [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) conventions. I will have a look. Another point, the default to the user name as database name shouldn't work since they are different, no?

Comment: Also these `bash -c -w -U ..` are going to fail as there is no program e.g. `psql` to use the connection settings. And this `FATAL, role "root` would indicate that the scripts are being run as `root` and the `env` variables are not being set. `psql -U postgres` means it will connect to database `postgres`. `psql` has no knowledge of your made up `env` variables so it will not use `POSTGRES_DB=mydb`.

Comment: ah sorry, my mistake in writing down, yes, of course there is `psql` in front. And yes, the ENV vars are not read since `kubectl exec -it pg-red-0 -- bash -c echo $POSTGRES_USER` returns nothing. But people seem to use this!

Comment: If you have a look at [this link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40846), it says that using `bash`, Postgres should be aware of his environment, so read $POSTGRES.

Comment: I don't use Kubernetes, but for those that do and could be of more help,  I would say you need to add to your question the configuration file you are using to declare them.

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere in the config where you making them `env` variables. I think you need to take a look at either [Env var](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) or [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/)

Comment: I believe I am indeed using a ConfigMap

Comment: Yes but from the link I provided it does not look like you are defining the `env` variables correctly. Pretty sure `data:` is not the way to do this.

Comment: No, this is correct. The app receives them correctly otherwise nothing would work, not just that.

Comment: It is correct in that you can specify `data:`, it is incorrect in that as you have shown the `env` variables are not set. Read the links I posted. Also nowhere in the link you posted do they use `data:` they use `env:`.

Comment: They are set. `kubectl exec -it pg-dep-0 -- sh
   / # echo $POSTGRES_USER
   postgres   <-- correct`

Comment: Link from [kubernetes configmap] (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#configmaps-and-pods). `Env`   is in a pod. The problem is not here.

Comment: Look at this [Config](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/kubernetes-configmaps/) Example-3: Use Kubernetes ConfigMap to declare environment variables.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, but again,  I showed you that the pods **know** these variables so this is not the problem. You may read more in the official documentation if you want to learn Kubernetes, and so should I.